# Webpack: Custom loader - reuse file extension

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, webpack-loader

I'm working on writing a loader for `filename.xyz.json` files.

Now since Webpack version 2, Webpack support loading JSON files out of the box.
So I've managed to get my loader to work when working when using a completely custom file extension like `.xyz.jayson`.

But because I'm using `.json` the other, already existing loader gets triggered after my loader did his magic, which will cause an error because at this point it's not JSON anymore. How can I prevent that?

If I understand the Webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline) correctly, the `!!` prefix with inline usage would do just that. But I would like to disable post/pre loaders in the config. Is this possible?

Also, I was thinking of actually using that given JSON loader instead of dodging it, because why parse the JSON myself, when there is already a loader for it? But I don't quite sure if that is possible since the returned source from the JSON is already returned as `module.export`. Would I need to strip the `module.export` and then run `JSON.parse` to work with it as an actual js object instead of a string?

So as a quick summary:

I'd like to either to **not** trigger the JSON loader at all, and parse the JSON myself to manipulate it or **use the built-in** JSON loader first and then manipulate the JSON data file myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Setting the type of my rule to `javascript/auto` gave me the expected result.

More information [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10098)